# Scala : Product with Serializable does not take parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

My objectif is to read Data from a csv file and convert my rdd to dataframe in scala/spark. This is my code :

```
package xxx.DataScience.CompensationStudy

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


object CompensationAnalysis {

  case class GetDF(profil_date:String, profil_pays:String, param_tarif2:String, param_tarif3:String, dt_titre:String, dt_langues:String,
    dt_diplomes:String, dt_experience:String, dt_formation:String, dt_outils:String, comp_applications:String, 
    comp_interventions:String, comp_competence:String)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CompensationAnalysis ")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._


    val lines = sc.textFile("C:/Users/../Downloads/CompensationStudy.csv").flatMap { l => 


      l.split(",") match {

        case field: Array[String] if field.size > 13 => Some(field(0), field(1), field(2), field(3), field(4), field(5), field(6), field(7), field(8), field(9), field(10), field(11), field(12))

        case field: Array[String] if field.size == 1 => Some((field(0), "default value"))

        case _ => None 
      }


    }
```

At this stade, I had the error : **Product with Serializable does not take parameters**

```
    val summary = lines.collect().map(x => GetDF(x("profil_date"), x("profil_pays"), x("param_tarif2"), x("param_tarif3"), x("dt_titre"), x("dt_langues"), x("dt_diplomes"), x("dt_experience"), x("dt_formation"), x("dt_outils"), x("comp_applications"), x("comp_interventions"), x("comp_competence")))

    val sum_df = summary.toDF()

    df.printSchema


  }

}
```

This is a screenshot :

[image]

Help please ?

Comment: Your problem is in the `flatMap` defining `lines`. The only type the compiler is able to infer is `RDD[Product with Serializable]`, because you have different types in your `Option`s.

Answer (score 2):

You have several things you should improve. The most urgent problem, which causes the exception, is, as @CyrilleCorpet points out, " the three different lines in the pattern matching return values of types `Some[Tuple13]`, `Some[Tuple2]` and `None.type`. The least-upper-bound is then `Option[Product with Serializable]` which complies with `flatMap`'s signature (where the result should be an `Iterable[T]`) modulo some implicit conversion."

Basically, if you had `Some[Tuple13]`, `Some[Tuple13]`, and `None` *or* `Some[Tuple2]`, `Some[Tuple2]`, and `None`, you would be better off.

Also, pattern matching on types is generally a bad idea because of type erasure, and pattern matching isn't even great anyway for your situation.

So you could set default values in your case class:

```
case class GetDF(profile_date: String, 
                 profile_pays: String = "default", 
                 param_tarif2: String = "default", 
                 ...
)
```

Then in your lambda:

```
val tokens = l.split
if (l.length > 13) {
   Some(GetDf(l(0), l(1), l(2)...))
} else if (l.length == 1) {
   Some(GetDf(l(0)))
} else {
   None
}
```

Now in all cases you are returning `Option[GetDF]`. You can `flatMap` the `RDD` to get rid of all the `None`s and keep only `GetDF` instances.

Comment: Actually, the three different lines in the pattern matching return values of types `Some[Tuple13]`, `Some[Tuple2]` and `None.type`. The least-upper-bound is then `Option[Product with Serializable]` which complies with `flatMap`'s signature (where the result should be an `Iterable[T]`) modulo some implicit conversion. This doesn't change in anyway the validity of your solution.